# How to hide wireframe while turning on the 'face selection mask' in texture paint?

Tags: texture-painting

In texture paint , i hide some faces by turn on the 'face selection mask' button. But turning on this button will make the wireframe appear on the object surface. This is annoying, how can i hide the wireframe ?

Comment: it's looks like that it is impossible. Only if you turn off all overlays in 2.80

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Face Selection Mask in Texture Paint is exactly what it says - to use the selection of faces to create paint areas that are active and allowing the user to limit the spray of paint on the model surface. The wireframe drawing on the surface informs the user of what they can select, and the change in object color when deselected allows the user to differentiate between the selected and deselected faces. Hiding the wireframe is not logical when using face selection masking, and getting rid of the wireframe is only possible by turning off the face selection mask mode.

Comment: Thanks ... but I'm painting on some faces while the other foreground faces is covering (i have very irregular shape) so it's hard because i have to rotate camera around until i have clear view to paint and sometime i can't find the correct angle . So the best way to do this is to hide those foreground faces so i did it using face selectioin mask , now i can paint freely on target faces. In this case, hiding those wireframe is logical  for me,  i know my working area and i don't need that wireframe guide. the only solution is to turn off all overlays.